# Calculating a line integral using Green's theorem in a region with a singularity

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, greens-theorem

**Problem**:
Calculate the line integral

$$
\int_{A}\frac{y\,dx-(x+1)\,dy}{x^2+y^2+2x+1}
$$

where $A$ is the line $|x|+|y|=4$, travelling clockwise and making one rotation.

[image: The line visualized.]

**Answer**: $-2\pi$

**Solution**:

The denominator $x^2+y^2+2x+1$ can be rewritten as $(x+1)^2+y^2$, which shows that there is a singularity at $(-1, 0)$.

Now, if
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
M &= \frac{y}{(x+1)^2+y^2} \\[2pt] 
N &= \frac{-(x+1)}{(x+1)^2+y^2} 
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

then
$$
\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}
$$

Thus, Green's theorem yields:

$$
\tag{0}\int_{A-B} M\,dx + N\,dy 
= \iint_{D} \frac{\partial N}{\partial x} 
- \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\,dx\,dy = 0
$$

$B$ can be parameterized with
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
x &= -1 + \cos t \\
y &= \sin t,
\end{aligned}\right. 
\qquad 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi
$$
which finally yields
\begin{align}
\int_{A} M\,dx + N\,dy 
&= \int_{B} M\,dx + N\,dy \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} -\frac{\sin^2 t}{1} - \frac{\cos^2 t}{1}\,dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} - 1 \,dt \\[2pt] 
&= -2\pi  
\end{align}

**I don't understand how to interpret the "$A - B$" on the left-hand side of equation $(0)$.** It seems to me that it does not represent a simple closed curve, as shown in the image above. How can Green's theorem then still be used?

Also, why is $B$ a unit circle around the singularity? Why not a circle of radius $2$, or a square? Why is $B$ necessary at all? I can't figure out why $B$ appears as part of the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regions in the plane and curves that bound them all have orientation. These are defined in a specific way that makes Green's Theorem work. By convention, a *positively* oriented closed, simple curve traces the boundary of a region with the interior of the region always on the left (and the exterior on the right). This works just fine if the region is simply connected (topologically equivalent to a disk) and so its boundary is a single curve.

However, if the region is not simply connected (it has holes), then the boundary consists of a union of multiple simple closed curves. In Green's Theorem, the integrand must be continuous on the entire region, which is why in your example, we have to remove some region around the singularity. This produces the region inside the square $A$ but outside the circle $B$.

To orient its boundary *positively*, we need to traverse $A$ counterclockwise and $B$ clockwise. (Check for yourself that this keeps the interior of the region always on the left of either curve.) Now, an integral over the entire boundary is an integral over $A \cup B$, but to indicate that $B$ is meant to be clockwise (its interior is actually the exterior of our region in question), we might write this as $A \cup (-B)$, or just $A - B$ for short, especially since when we integrate over a domain consisting of two disjoint pieces, we're just adding the respective integrals, the latter with a minus sign:
$$
\int_{A-B} f(\mathbf{r}) \, d\mathbf{r} 
= \int_A f(\mathbf{r}) \, d\mathbf{r} 
- \int_B f(\mathbf{r}) \, d\mathbf{r}. 
$$

Now, your calculation actually involves the reverse orientation of the square (and hence the circle), so there is a global minus sign, but the principle still applies.

Comment: Hi, thanks for writing and fixing my LaTeX. I upvoted your answer and will try to make sense of it as soon as possible (and probably ask annoying follow-ups).

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer. How difficult is it to understand the definition of a region so that it complies with Green's theorem for an undergrad? I'm failing to see how the union of multiple simple closed curves is allowed to be used as the boundary. Also, I'm still not comfortable with the choice of $B$, why did it have to be a unit circle? If the radius was 2, the answer would be $-4\pi$, and I find this deeply unnerving .

Comment: One beautiful consequence of Green's theorem, which leads naturally into topology, is that it doesn't matter what shape or size the curve $B$ is, as long as it's simple, closed, and encircles the singularity once in the same direction as $B$! This certainly doesn't constitute a proof of the above claim, but just to get a feel for this result, try making $B$ be a circle of arbitrary but fixed radius $r$, and observe that the calculation doesn't end up depending on $r$.

Comment: Oh dear, I can see now that the answer is in fact $-2\pi$ regardless of radius (and not $-4\pi$ for radius $2$). Here comes a disastrously dumb question: does it make sense to ask if there is a "minimum" curve $B$ that can acceptably encircle the singularity? Curl has been described as "local circulation" to me. Is the curl at (-1, 0) meaningful in any way? I realize that it is 0, but would it make sense to substitute $B$ with the curl at the point of singularity? Finally, do you perhaps have some books or resources on topology that would make sense for someone on my level?

Comment: I recommend this paperback to students, particularly if you're interested in the physics that motivated the development of vector calculus and its various theorems: [*Div, Grad, Curl, and All That*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/sembQgAACAAJ) by H.M. Schey